# Подскажите, как оформить кусок кода с помощью рекурсии

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
hashes = ["1115dd800feaacefdf481f1f9070374a2a81e27880f187396db67958b207cbad",
          "3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b",
          "74e1bb62f8dabb8125a58852b63bdf6eaef667cb56ac7f7cdba6d7305c50a22f"]
letters = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
result = {}
for l1 in letters:
    for l2 in letters:
        for l3 in letters:
            for l4 in letters:
                for l5 in letters:
                    word = bytes(l1+l2+l3+l4+l5, encoding='utf-8')
                    if hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest() in hashes:
                        result[hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest()] = word
print(result)
```

Выше сам код.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам нужна именно рекурсия? Или нормальный компактный код?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, если есть способ привести код в порядок без рекурсии - то этот вариант тоже хорош.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) перебирает все комбинации. Заодно преобразование в байты вынесено из цикла, чтобы его как-то разгрузить.

```
import hashlib
import itertools


hashes = ["1115dd800feaacefdf481f1f9070374a2a81e27880f187396db67958b207cbad",
          "3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b",
          "74e1bb62f8dabb8125a58852b63bdf6eaef667cb56ac7f7cdba6d7305c50a22f"]
letters = tuple(bytes(c, encoding='utf-8') for c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
result = {}
for p in itertools.product(letters, repeat=5):
    word = b''.join(p)
    digest = hashlib.sha256(word).hexdigest()
    if digest in hashes:
        result[digest] = word
print(result)
```

> ```
> $ time python product.py
> {'3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b':
> b'apple',
> '74e1bb62f8dabb8125a58852b63bdf6eaef667cb56ac7f7cdba6d7305c50a22f':
> b'mmmmm',
> '1115dd800feaacefdf481f1f9070374a2a81e27880f187396db67958b207cbad':
> b'zyzzx'}
>
> real  0m12.201s
> user  0m12.196s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь